# Does a Norwegian company with work in Norway, who hires a U.S. citizen in U.S. (not expat) as remote independent contractor, have to file 1099?

Tags: taxes, us-citizens, foreign-employment

I am a U.S. citizen based in the U.S., working remotely as an independent contractor for Norwegian companies with work in Norway (interpreting and voice over). I have to pay taxes on my income in the US, but does the Norwegian company have to file a 1099 or can it just be treated as "other source" income? Similarly, do I have to pay Norwegian income tax?

Comment: The vast majority of the nations of the world only tax income based on actual residency.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the Norwegian company has to file a 1099 is a matter for that company.  From your perspective, you report the income on your US income tax return, and if they send you a 1099, you include it.  If they don't, it's not a problem that you haven't included one with your return.

I am fairly certain that you do not need to pay Norwegian income tax, since you are working entirely outside of Norway and do not reside in Norway, but I am far from certain.  However, it looks like you may [need to collect value-added tax](https://www.skatteetaten.no/en/business-and-organisation/vat-and-duties/vat/foreign/) and remit it to the Norwegian revenue authority.  I'm not sure whether this would count as "electronic services," but if it does:

> **VAT On E-Commerce - VOEC**
> Foreign providers of electronic services to Norwegian consumers are obliged to collect and pay VAT. From 1 April 2020 this also applies to suppliers of low value goods.